# How to proceed so that I can scan ? Canon DR-M160

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, canon, sane

I connected my Canon DR-M160 scanner via USB,
to my Lubuntu laptop.

I get:

> lsusb
>   Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1083:163e Canon Electronics, Inc.

So it is detected !?
I guess I now have to install sane-canon_dr ?!

How to proceed so that I can scan ?

Answer (score 0):

Just from your Dash search for the scanning default app named [simple scan](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/simple-scan/). Open it and you can use your scanner.

Refer to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Scanners) for more info.